# configure code blocks according to two cmake file

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am new to opencv i am trying to find the feature points in face in opencv 3.0 . I am using CLM framework .The examples in the frame work build perfectly when i build it using cmake . I found a CMakelists.txt in the root directory of the frame work and in the example folder . Can anyone help me to configure code blocks according to these 2 cmake file or help me to make a single cmake file to execte my project.

CMakelists.txt [in root folder]

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (CLM_framework)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")

if(WIN32)
    include_directories(lib/3rdParty/OpenCV3.0/include)
    include_directories(lib/3rdParty/OpenCV3.0/include/opencv)

    if(MSVC_VERSION == 1600)
        link_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/3rdParty/OpenCV3.0/x86/v100/lib )
    endif(MSVC_VERSION)

    if(MSVC_VERSION == 1700)
        link_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/3rdParty/OpenCV3.0/x86/v110/lib )
    endif(MSVC_VERSION)

    set(OpenCVLibraries 
            debug opencv_world300d 

            optimized opencv_world300
            )

    if (MSVC)       

        if(MSVC_VERSION == 1600)
            file(GLOB files "lib/3rdParty/OpenCV3.0/x86/v100/bin/*.dll")
        endif(MSVC_VERSION)

        if(MSVC_VERSION == 1700)
            file(GLOB files "lib/3rdParty/OpenCV3.0/x86/v110/bin/*.dll")
        endif(MSVC_VERSION)

        foreach(file ${files})
          file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release)
        endforeach()

        foreach(file ${files})
          file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug)
        endforeach()
    endif(MSVC)
endif(WIN32)

if(UNIX)
    find_package( OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED )
    find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)
    MESSAGE("Boost information:") 
    MESSAGE("  Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}") 
    MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}") 
    MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}") 

    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}/boost)
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}) 
endif(UNIX)

find_package(TBB REQUIRED)

# Move CLM model
file(GLOB files "lib/local/CLM/model/*.txt")
foreach(file ${files})
    if (MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug/model)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release/model)
    else(MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/model)
    endif(MSVC)
endforeach()

file(GLOB files "lib/local/CLM/model/detection_validation/*.txt")
foreach(file ${files})
    if (MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug/model/detection_validation)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release/model/detection_validation)
    else(MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/model/detection_validation)
    endif(MSVC)
endforeach()

file(GLOB files "lib/local/CLM/model/patch_experts/*.txt")
foreach(file ${files})
    if (MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug/model/patch_experts)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release/model/patch_experts)
    else(MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/model/patch_experts)
    endif(MSVC)
endforeach()

file(GLOB files "lib/local/CLM/model/pdms/*.txt")
foreach(file ${files})
    if (MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug/model/pdms)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release/model/pdms)
    else(MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/model/pdms)
    endif(MSVC)
endforeach()

# Move OpenCV classifiers
file(GLOB files "lib/3rdParty/OpenCV3.0/classifiers/*.xml")
foreach(file ${files})
    if (MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug/classifiers)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release/classifiers)
    else(MSVC)
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/classifiers)
    endif(MSVC)
endforeach()

if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "GNU")
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpversion OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
    if (GCC_VERSION VERSION_LESS 4.7)
        set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -msse -msse2 -msse3")
    else ()
        set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -msse -msse2 -msse3")
    endif ()
else ()
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -msse -msse2 -msse3")
endif ()

# Boost
if(WIN32)
    include_directories(lib/3rdParty/boost)
    include_directories(lib/3rdParty/boost/boost)
    link_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/3rdParty/boost/lib )
else()
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

# dlib
include_directories(lib/3rdParty/dlib/include)

# dlib library
add_subdirectory(lib/3rdParty/dlib)

# CLM library (ordering matters)
add_subdirectory(lib/local/CLM)
add_subdirectory(lib/local/FaceAnalyser)
# executables
add_subdirectory(exe/SimpleCLMImg)
add_subdirectory(exe/SimpleCLM)
add_subdirectory(exe/MultiTrackCLM)
add_subdirectory(exe/FeatureExtraction)
```

CMakelists.txt [in exe/MultiTrackCLM]

```
# Local libraries
include_directories(${CLM_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

include_directories(../../lib/local/CLM/include)

add_executable(MultiTrackCLM MultiTrackCLM.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MultiTrackCLM CLM)
target_link_libraries(MultiTrackCLM dlib)

if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(MultiTrackCLM ${OpenCVLibraries})
endif(WIN32)
if(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(MultiTrackCLM ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${TBB_LIBRARIES})
endif(UNIX)

install (TARGETS MultiTrackCLM DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```